# Elixir: float to formatted string

Tags: string, floating-point, elixir

I do a simple code kata in [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/), solving followed problem:

> Series: 1 + 1/4 + 1/7 + 1/10 + 1/13 + 1/16 +...

I've got an error about test like this:

```
series sum (6.0ms)
  1) test series sum (TestSeries)
     fixture:6
     Assertion with == failed
     code: sum(0) == "0.00"
     lhs:  '0.00'
     rhs:  "0.00"
     stacktrace:
       fixture:7
```

Are they different in Elixir, `'0.00'` and `"0.00"`?

And formatting the float to string is hard work like this?:

```
# My Solution
defmodule Series do
  def sum(n) do
    n
    |> gen_series
    |> do_sum
    |> make_format
  end

  def gen_series(n) do
    if n == 0 do
      [0.00]
    else
      for x <- 1..n, do: 1/(1+3*(x-1))
    end
  end

  def do_sum(series) do
    series
    |> Enum.reduce(&(&1+&2))
  end

  def make_format(sum) do
    :io_lib.format("~.2f", [sum])
    |> Enum.at(0)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they different in Elixir, '0.00' and "0.00"?

yes they are

single-quote literal are `charlist` which is list of code points.

to convert float to string use the following:

```
def make_format(sum) do
    :io_lib.format("~.2f", [sum])
    # use to_string instead of Enum.at(0) which returns charlist
    |> to_string()
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll remind the difference between `charlist` and `string`. But I hope there is a simple API for this..

Answer (score 0):

To round a float to a given precision and format it as a string (binary), you can use `:erlang.float_to_binary/2`.

```
:erlang.float_to_binary(987.3, [decimals: 2]) # => "987.30"
:erlang.float_to_binary(387.39947423, [decimals: 4]) => "387.3995"
```

This function can also give you a scientific or compact format. See `h :erlang.float_to_binary/2` in `iex`.